# Android: Change part of Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've come a long way with my app and have a Taskbar with a Slide-In-Menu. The Problem is, that my Buttons a opening new Activities, so the Bar is loading each time new and it does not look beautiful at all.

I'd like to have a constant "Wrapper" Layout and only change the contents (with another xml-layout?). What is the best way to achieve it? Fragments? Can someone help me with a good tutorial on this Topic?

This is my navigation-structure with Scrollviews:

[Navigation concept](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h690txwjxjb2724/Navigation.jpg?dl=0)

Thanks in advance

Arti

Comment: For some reason that link doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The best pattern for this is a [Navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

There is [sample](https://developer.android.com/samples/NavigationDrawer/index.html) in android documentation. Also check [this example](https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template) for Material design.

If you use Android studio, there is a template of drawer activity which you can modify to your needs.

Comment: I already have a drawer with a few Items. I've made a short videoclip, not the best quality, but it illustrates my problem:
[link](https://youtu.be/yC4dTEWHgEo)
Every Button opens a new activity, but I want the action bar to stay the same, only the content should change.